# Generate & store unescaped strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I generate and store a **completely unescaped** string in PHP?

In JS I can do it this way:

```js
// Generates unescaped string
const unescaped = String.raw`\/pass\nfoo=`;
// Interacts with unescaped string without changing it
const pass = unescaped.concat(`i15`);

console.log(pass);
// -> \/pass\nfoo=i15
```

while without [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) it'd work differently:

```js
console.log(`\/pass\nfoo=`);
// 1. /pass
// 2. foo=
```

How could I achieve the same in PHP?

Seems like [the manual doesn't mention](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) this topic.

Comment: What's wrong with `$str = '\/pass\nfoo=';`?

Comment: @miken32 that will work for everything but \\ and \'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you could just use single quoted strings:

```
$unescaped = '\/pass\nfoo=';
$unescaped .= 'i15';
echo $unescaped;
```

Output:

```
\/pass\nfoo=i15
```

However there are two exceptions to this, when you have `\\` or `\'` in your string, both of which **are** treated as an escaped character i.e. `\` or `'`. e.g.

```
$unescaped = '\/pa\\s\'s\nfoo=';
$unescaped .= 'i15';
echo $unescaped;
```

Output:

```
\/pa\s's\nfoo=i15
```

You can work around that limitation by using [`nowdoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax:

```
$unescaped = <<<'EOT'
\/pa\\s\'s\nfoo=
EOT;
$unescaped .= <<<'EOT'
i15
EOT;
echo $unescaped;
```

Output:

```
\/pa\\s\'s\nfoo=i15
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LE8tG)